# xmlstarlet extract values from Office 365 XML Files

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am attempting to extract the IPv4 Addresses and URLs for each product in the Office 365 portfolio from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=533185.  I would like to create an input file for updating Firewall and Proxy server rules.

Snippet from XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products updated="8/31/2016">
  <product name="WAC">
    <addresslist type="IPv6">
      <address>2a01:111:f406:8800::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:400::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:1c01::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:9400::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:2402::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:a804::/64</address>
      <address>2a01:111:f406:b401::/64</address>
      <address>2620:1ec:c11::204</address>
      <address>2a01:111:202c::204</address>
      <address>2620:1ec:c11::205</address>
      <address>2a01:111:202c::205</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="IPv4">
      <address>13.69.187.20/32</address>
      <address>13.70.184.242/32</address>
      <address>13.71.155.176/32</address>
      <address>13.75.153.216/32</address>
      <address>13.76.140.48/32</address>
      <address>13.78.114.39/32</address>
      <address>13.85.84.102/32</address>
      <address>13.88.248.161/32</address>
      <address>13.88.254.212/32</address>
      <address>13.94.209.165/32</address>
      <address>23.103.183.15/32</address>
      <address>40.68.166.51/32</address>
      <address>40.74.130.243/32</address>
      <address>40.74.138.42/32</address>
      <address>40.76.54.124/32</address>
      <address>40.86.230.88/32</address>
      <address>40.114.192.209/32</address>
      <address>40.117.226.146/32</address>
      <address>40.126.236.216/32</address>
      <address>40.127.79.139/32</address>
      <address>52.169.109.48/32</address>
      <address>52.172.13.171/32</address>
      <address>52.172.153.104/32</address>
      <address>52.175.25.142/32</address>
      <address>52.232.128.169/32</address>
      <address>104.40.225.204/32</address>
      <address>104.41.62.54/32</address>
      <address>104.211.103.207/32</address>
      <address>104.211.229.230/32</address>
      <address>104.214.38.136/32</address>
      <address>104.215.194.17/32</address>
      <address>134.170.27.86/32</address>
      <address>134.170.48.20/32</address>
      <address>134.170.48.22/32</address>
      <address>134.170.65.86/32</address>
      <address>134.170.170.86/32</address>
      <address>137.116.172.39/32</address>
      <address>137.135.65.72/32</address>
      <address>191.235.87.181/32</address>
      <address>191.237.40.220/32</address>
    </addresslist>
    <addresslist type="URL">
      <address>*.officeapps.live.com</address>
      <address>*.cdn.office.net</address>
    </addresslist>
  </product>
  <product name="Sway">
```

I have figured out out to list the products which can be used as to cycle through the products to get the end result but I can seem to get past filtering on a particular product and IPv4 address.

```
./xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/products/product'  -v @name -n Downloads/O365IPAddresses.xml
WAC
Sway
Planner
Yammer
OneNote
OfficeiPad
OfficeMobile
ProPlus
RCA
LYO
SPO
Office365Video
identity
EXO
CRLs
o365
EOP
```

I have tried many variations of the following and no output.

```
./xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//root/products/product[name="WAC"]/addresslist[type="IPv4"]'  Downloads/O365IPAddresses.xml
```

Ultimately I would like to get to a text file that has something like the following.

```
WAC,IPv4,13.69.187.20/32
WAC,IPv4,13.70.184.242/32
.....
.....
WAC,URL,*.officeapps.live.com
```

I can then use this csv file to update the collection of Firewalls and Proxy servers in my company.

Many thanks in advance for the help.